# FTP file upload via webpage - Why won't it work for larger files?

Tags: php, ftp

Currently tearing my hair out over this ongoing problem with uploading large files so I'm hoping someone can help with this!

I have this upload script that works perfectly with small files, however when I try larger files I get an error message "Filename cannot be empty" which I am finding very confusing.

The upload is going to a third-party ftp host.

This is the script as it is:-

```
    $file = $_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'];
    $remote_file = $_FILES['ufile']['name'];

    $conn_id = ftp_connect("www.ftphostinguk.com");
    $ftp_user_name = "****";
    $ftp_user_pass = "***********";

    $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

    if (ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_BINARY)) {
      echo "successfully uploaded $file\n";
    } else {
     echo "There was a problem while uploading $file\n";
    }

    ftp_close($conn_id);
```

I think the thing that's most confusing me is why it's working for small files but not for larger files?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit to add:** When I use "echo" to display the filename I am getting a blank response for the larger file.
I'm wondering if I am misunderstanding the fundamental process of uploading a file in this manner? I assumed that the temp file was uploaded to the ftp server, but is it possible that the file is uploaded first to the webserver?

Comment: What is your upload_max_filesize value in your php.ini?

Comment: @Pekka - the test file is just over 10m, ultimately this could be anything up to 200m. @etbal I have no access to php.ini. My original approach was to attempt to upload the files to the webhost but they have an upload size limit so I created an account with a third party ftp host

Answer (score 3):

Your PHP script is most likely timing out, try adding these to the top of your page and tweaking the settings (300 seconds is 5 minutes):

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '10M');  
ini_set('post_max_size', '10M');  
ini_set('max_input_time', 300);  
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
```

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid this doesn't seem to work for me. I've changed the settings to 30m and a timeout delay of 10000

Comment: Is there a file size limit on the host server and is there enough space?

Comment: You mean the host to which I'm uploading the file? No limit and its a new empty account

Comment: It may be that you need do edit the php.ini file directly because of permissions, try doing this and then recompiling.

Comment: Sadly I don't have access to this.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem because PHP won't accept large uploaded file (`$_FILES`)

You can change the behaviour in php.ini:

```
ini_set('max_input_time','');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '');  
ini_set('post_max_size', '');
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, looks like you were just 2 seconds slower :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the answers that have been provided would probably fix my issue had I access to php.ini, unfortunately I don't and it seems from my research today that my problem is with the webhosts file limits.

So to fix my problem I have chosen a different angle to attack from which to attack it. I have created a form that logs directly into the ftphost's web-based interface, a net2ftp installation. Its not the solution I wanted but other than change webhost it seems the only viable one.
Once again I'd like to thank the knowledgeable folk here for their input.